# passing special characters with encodeURI in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, encode

I have an HTML input field linked to a button with an onclick function in javascript that can pass the textfield value to a textfield of another page. While passing the values from one page to another via an URL request of a JSP, I found out that encoding the values with `encodeURI()` gets:

- £ --> Â£  (2 signs !!)
- ö --> Ã¶  (2 signs !!)

When I use Javscript `escape()` I get the proper encodings, but unfortunately the + sign would disappear. Is there are better solution to have some sort of stable encoding of characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`encodeURI()` encodes using UTF-8 encoding, which is why you see the two signs for encoding one characters (it's normal).

If you want to use escape and still keep the `+` sign, you can use the following:

```
function mod_escape(value) {
  value = escape(value);
  return value.replace(/\+/g, '%2B');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use encodeURIComponent() on each single key=value pair and decodeURIComponent at second page for each key=value pair.